# How can I load a sound file into memory using NAudio and use it later?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, memory-management, naudio

I'm playing the same sound files (randomly choosing between them) 5 times a second, and I'm always loading into memory, so the program uses a lot of memory. How could I load the sound file into memory, and start it from there? I'm using NAudio. Current code:

```
var sound = "sounds/test.mp3";
using (var audioFile = new AudioFileReader(sound))
using (var outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent())
{
    outputDevice.Init(audioFile);
    outputDevice.Play();
    while (outputDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    threadStop();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the whole issue by using the code found in this [article](http://markheath.net/post/fire-and-forget-audio-playback-with). 
It uses the `MixingSampleProvider`. I load the sounds into a custom class called: `CachedSound`. And then I play them using another class called: `AudioPlaybackEngine`. Which handles the mixer, and I use the `CachedSoundSampleProvider` class to read the cached sound.

The code looks like this:

```
class AudioPlaybackEngine : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IWavePlayer outputDevice;
    private readonly MixingSampleProvider mixer;

    public AudioPlaybackEngine(int sampleRate = 44100, int channelCount = 2)
    {
        outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
        mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(sampleRate, channelCount));
        mixer.ReadFully = true;
        outputDevice.Init(mixer);
        outputDevice.Play();
    }

    public void PlaySound(string fileName)
    {
        var input = new AudioFileReader(fileName);
        AddMixerInput(new AutoDisposeFileReader(input));
    }

    private ISampleProvider ConvertToRightChannelCount(ISampleProvider input)
    {
        if (input.WaveFormat.Channels == mixer.WaveFormat.Channels)
        {
            return input;
        }
        if (input.WaveFormat.Channels == 1 && mixer.WaveFormat.Channels == 2)
        {
            return new MonoToStereoSampleProvider(input);
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not yet implemented this channel count conversion");
    }

    public void PlaySound(CachedSound sound)
    {
        AddMixerInput(new CachedSoundSampleProvider(sound));
    }

    private void AddMixerInput(ISampleProvider input)
    {
        mixer.AddMixerInput(ConvertToRightChannelCount(input));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        outputDevice.Dispose();
    }

    public static readonly AudioPlaybackEngine Instance = new AudioPlaybackEngine(44100, 2);
}

class CachedSound
{
    public float[] AudioData { get; private set; }
    public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; private set; }
    public CachedSound(string audioFileName)
    {
        using (var audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(audioFileName))
        {
            // TODO: could add resampling in here if required
            WaveFormat = audioFileReader.WaveFormat;
            var wholeFile = new List<float>((int)(audioFileReader.Length / 4));
            var readBuffer= new float[audioFileReader.WaveFormat.SampleRate * audioFileReader.WaveFormat.Channels];
            int samplesRead;
            while((samplesRead = audioFileReader.Read(readBuffer,0,readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                wholeFile.AddRange(readBuffer.Take(samplesRead));
            }
            AudioData = wholeFile.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

class CachedSoundSampleProvider : ISampleProvider
{
    private readonly CachedSound cachedSound;
    private long position;

    public CachedSoundSampleProvider(CachedSound cachedSound)
    {
        this.cachedSound = cachedSound;
    }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var availableSamples = cachedSound.AudioData.Length - position;
        var samplesToCopy = Math.Min(availableSamples, count);
        Array.Copy(cachedSound.AudioData, position, buffer, offset, samplesToCopy);
        position += samplesToCopy;
        return (int)samplesToCopy;
    }

    public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get { return cachedSound.WaveFormat; } }
}

// This class automatically disposes the file reader that it contains.
class AutoDisposeFileReader : ISampleProvider
{
    private readonly AudioFileReader reader;
    private bool isDisposed;
    public AutoDisposeFileReader(AudioFileReader reader)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.WaveFormat = reader.WaveFormat;
    }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (isDisposed)
            return 0;
        int read = reader.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        if (read == 0)
        {
            reader.Dispose();
            isDisposed = true;
        }
        return read;
    }

    public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to use this solution you have posted and I can't hear anything through the speakers though I can see the green bar moving up and down in the "Volume mixer" but nothing is shown in the Settings->Speakers' Volume. Help?

Comment: Can you hear anything else? ( Youtube, Music things like this)

Comment: Yes, I can, every other app is ok but mine is not outputting real sound despite the fact it shows up in the "volume mixer".

Comment: Ok, I finally found out what my problem was, the AudioPlaybackEngine being static, it actually was instantiated in another thread than the one in which I called it. And I don't exactly know why but that was preventing it from working. It now works since I instantiate AudioPlaybackEngine in the same thread than the one where I call PlaySound().

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the `using` blocks then `audioFile` and `outputDevice` will not be disposed. You can then retain them in memory, and the same references will be used each time you play the audio.

With `using` blocks, you are repeatedly instantiating NAudio objects whose memory may not be deallocated immediately.

```
var sound = "sounds/test.mp3";
var audioFile = new AudioFileReader(sound);
var outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
outputDevice.Init(audioFile);
outputDevice.Play();
while (outputDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
threadStop();
```

Comment: But these variables are replaced ~5 times a second so there would be memory leaks all over the place.

Comment: Then instantiate a set of objects for each unique audio file. Updating your question may help in clarifying what you are doing. Your question is simply using a single audio file source and you state that it is "the same sound file."

Comment: You understand it right, I have multiple sound files. They are played when a key is pressed. If I understand it right, I should instantiate a new AudioFileReader for every sound file?(but only once)

Comment: That would be my approach, to instantiate a new `AudioFileReader` for each file.